# How To Remote Monitor A Webcam Aforge C# Solution?

Tags: c#, webcam, monitor, aforge

I'm currently trying to develop a simple watch-over system using AForge lib and UsbCameras ( Webcams ), the system would be installed in a main computer in a store for example, and it could be accessed maybe by a WebSite or just a WPF solution in another computer, other network, but remotely acessing the server's cameras.
What's the correct way I should implement this?

I've used AForge to show and record camera's image, but I've never acctually "streamed" the image to another computer.

Comment: Using a remote software like TeamViewer doesn't seem to be a good solution at all...

Answer (score 0):

This [c# web camera](http://www.camera-sdk.com) software might help you. With this, you can stream the camera image to website, so you can remotely access it.